# Ruby on Rails / MySQL Special Characters In String Get Converted to "?" When Saving

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a user who's trying to register with a special character "Č".  During the registration process, the Č gets converted to a "?".  I'm using devise to handle the user registration and after stepping through the devise code, I can verify that the browser is returning the correct character.  The Č is even stored in the User model name attribute.  However, if I look at the database immediately after user.save is called, the ? is in the database.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

1. Ruby Version = 1.9.3p125
2. Rails Version = 3.2.12
3. MySQL = Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
4. Devise 2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look which encoding you use in your database.

Comment: How would I check that and what encoding should I use?

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.  My DB is stuck on Latin1 encoding.